# How to remove redundant code in php file

Tags: php, html

I am using following code atleast 10 time in my php file.

```
<span class="red">*</span>
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['nodistrict'])) {
 echo '<span class="red">&nbsp; Selecting a district is mandatory.</span>';
 }
?>
```

How can I write this at one place and call from several places.

Comment: create a function in a included php file and call it on the other pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something along the lines of this:

```
function showError($to_check, $mandatory_field)
{
    if(isset($to_check))
    {
        echo '<span class="red">&nbsp; Selecting a ' . $mandatory_field . ' is mandatory.</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A function like this:

```
function hasDistrict() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['nodistrict'])) {
        echo '<span class="red">&nbsp; Selecting a district is mandatory.</span>';
    }
}
```

Calling it like this in your code multiple times:

```
hasDistrict();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the code mixes HTML and PHP code, I would suggest putting it in a separate .php file and including it wherever you need it.